# To view dvi files under osx 10.9. X11 and Ghostscript issue

Tags: x11, ghostscript, osx-mavericks

I just have upgraded to os x 10.9 (clean install), but am finding issues with ghostscipt (or with X11-quartz). I need to view a dvi file (from latex) with this line command in Terminal

```
$ xdvi doc.dvi
```

The text appears fine, but the figures (.eps, .ps) do not show up. It left blank rectangles instaed. I get this error message

```
Warning: Unable to load any usable fontset
gs: Unknown device: x11
gs: Unrecoverable error: undefined in .uninstallpagedevice
gs: Operand stack:
gs:     defaultdevice
xdvi-xaw: Warning: Read_from_gs returned 0 bytes
```

P.S. I installed XQuartz 2.7.5 (xorg-server 1.14.4), and GPL Ghostscript 9.07.
Any guidance please?

Comment: please accept an anwer so that people don't come here trying to help, or specify what you wish of an answer

Answer (score 2):

The first answer is correct, as re-installing MacTex should relink gs to gs-X11.
You can also just relink it yourself. For instance:

```
 ls -l /usr/local/bin/gs

/usr/local/bin/gs -> /usr/local/bin/gs-noX11

 sudo ln -sf   /usr/local/bin/gs-X11 /usr/local/bin/gs
```

Now xdvi displays the images. Tested on Mavericks 10.9.4.

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled latex with MacTex again and now seems working fine.

Perhaps one needs to first install ghostscript then latex (?)

But note that I did some manipulations prior to this... In fact I reinstalled Ghostscript with mac ports. But even at that time it did not work, until I reinstalled Latex as highlighted above.